# Позиция курсора JTextPane

Tags: java, swing

Как можно узнать позицию куда я нажал на JTextPane? Мне нужно вставить картинку там где курсор возле текста мигает. Как вставить картинку я знаю, подскажите как позицию узнать.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на мой вопрос

```
Caret caret = textPane.getCaret();
caret.getMark();
```